# How to check whether any changes exist in two MSI files

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to generate a transform to MSI through Wix Library in C#.
In my program, I am merging all the properties to the copy of MSI and generating the transform by comparing the two MSIs (original and modified copy).

The program is crashing if all the properties are already exist in MSI.

How to check whether any two MSIs are having any differences or not?
So that program won't crash while generating the transform.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution to me is to simply query the Property table of the MSI file to see if that property is already there and then don't attempt to add it. Without knowing what your code actually looks like, why not just not catch the error that's caused by trying to add a duplicate property?

Otherwise look at WiDiffDB.vbs in the Windows Kit/SDK and see how that script compares two MSI files. Basically is calls MsiDatabaseGenerateTransform().

Comment: I am using Wix Library for creating the transform.In the code, I am browsing the msi and applying the properties and other standard to transform.
But sometimes, if the msi is already having all the standards then when we are comparing the msis(original and copy) then as there is no differences, it is causing runntime error.

So I want to keep a line of code before generating transform for checking any differences exist in the msi.If no difference, then I will skip the code of generating transform and will keep a message.

Comment: Exception occured is:

MSI Database
Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you dick
Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue, If
you dick Quit, the application will dose immediately.
The Windows Installer service failed to start. Contact your support
personnel.
-----------------------------------------------------

Below is the link for complete error when clicked on details button.

http://tny.cz/5587a956

Comment: Got the code required in the vbscript mentioned by PhilDW.
Thank you very much PhilDW.

Below is the related c# code for the same.

**bool difference = database.GenerateTransform(origDatabase, TRANSFORM);
                    if (difference)
                    {
                        database.CreateTransformSummaryInfo(origDatabase, TRANSFORM, TransformErrors.None, TransformValidations.None);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No modifications exist to create Transform");
                    }**